Changing dropdown value restults in text with white background

Update: After more browsing, I found this post where someone used void(0) at the end. This worked. :D

Using document.getElementById('request_custom_fields_18207184851991').value = 'lrtip_direct_rh_sub' on this webform will give the expected result of selecting desired dropdown item if pasted in the web browser console window.
enter image description here
However, if I wrap it inside javascript: {} and run it via a bookmarklet, the entire website is replaced with the value on a white background. I usually solve this with javascript: {document.getElementById('request_custom_fields_18207184851991').focus(), document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'lrtip_direct_rh_sub')}, but this does not make anything happen.
How can I solve this? :)

Also try ; return false; at the end

Ahh thanks @fdomn-m
